# LayerMask.NameToLayer not returning the expected value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the below code:

```
LayerMask targetLayer;
targetLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("TeamB");
```

However, instead of selecting my named layer, it selects 3 random ones (seemingly)? Default, TransparentFX and Ignore Raycast.

I also tried:

```
targetLayer = 7;
```

As I know that is the index of the layer, but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? How do I programatically set my named layer?

Comment: Have you tried ` LayerMask.GetMask("TeamB")` ?

Comment: Depending on what you are doing with that value.  It was right. A layer mask is different from a layer.

Comment: @Zserbinator that fixed it thanks very much, I didn't understand the difference between them. If you leave it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`LayerMask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) type is actually a `struct` and you are trying to assign it an integer value.

To get a `LayerMask` return type, you should use:

`targetLayer = LayerMask.GetMask("TeamB");`

The documentation explains the differences clearly:

- `NameToLayer(string layerName)` - Given a layer name, returns the layer index as defined by either a Builtin or a User Layer in the Tags and Layers manager.
- `GetMask(params string[] layerNames)` - Given a set of layer names as defined by either a Builtin or a User Layer in the Tags and Layers manager, returns the equivalent layer mask for all of them. You can pass in multiple names in a `string[]`.

Comment: This is confusing because the return type of GetMask is an int.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.GetMask.html

That is essentially the bit bask of 1's and 1's of the list of layer masks in your project.
So the value 6 would be.  0110 and this would include the second mask and third mask since the second and third bits are set.